# Why my NSDictionary that was from json sorted like this?

Tags: ios, json, swift, sorting, nsdictionary

I am trying to get the same sorted data like json in my `NSDictionary` when i accept a call. I dont know why i get the data like that? If there is a way, how to do it? Please Help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSDictionary always has no order. If you enumerate or print it, it will appear in basically random order. If you want to have it ordered, you'll have to get the keys and values and sort them yourself, or use something other than an NSDictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am just switch from Java Programmer.So,I am new to Swift.Any code help or which i have to use to make it sort like json

Comment: Any Help?Please,I am having trouble with that.

Comment: Hashmaps of Java are also not guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: Any Help please?I am stucking at that problem.Why i am not getting the same result like json?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not sorted. You will have to create an array to include all dictionary elements in order to sort it. In your case, to get an array of the keys sorted ascending

```
let sortedKeys = (dictionary.allKeys as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(
  [NSSortDescriptor(key:"self" ascending:true)])
```

Of course, if you were to use a true Swift dictionary, you can write this much more elegantly:

```
let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<)
```

Comment: I did as you told.It gives me sorted of keys like this http://puu.sh/i2bpq/366f181f7f.png. But it doesn't sort like json.Please check my json if u dont mind.With Regards.

Comment: u seen my completion handler right?i did the same to key from dictionary in swift.But the output is same as above image again.How do i need to do to get the same sort like json.Please help;(

Comment: Any Help?Please,I am having trouble with that.

Comment: No, I get a different output. If you get the same output, you did not output the sorted key array but your old object. With the sorted keys array you can do everything you need - eg. enumerate, access the values, etc.

Comment: Any Help please?I am stucking at that problem.Why i am not getting the same result like json?And i cant move forward until i solve that problem.:(

Comment: I think the answer above is complete. You should perhaps edit your question by adding an update, show the code how you implemented my answer, and give the diagnostics what is not working.